# Migrating SQL Server table to MySQL table with different encodings

Tags: mysql, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I have a table in **SQL** server that I want to move to a **MySQL** table. However, I want to change the default encoding from latin-1 to utf-8. I've tried running the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, which exports a csv to a file. It fails when I select a **utf-8** encoding for the "Code page". It is stored as **latin-1**.

Anyway, I was wondering how I could export this data and import it into MySQL as utf-8? I do not want to open a text-editor and save the exported file as UTF-8.

Comment: Which wizard?  Does the export wizard create a file?  What does the file look like?  How is the import performed?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` for some small sample.  That way, we can see if it is utf16 or something else.

Comment: The SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. So I right click a database and can select Tasks>Export data to start it up. I ran the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`  and received a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` encoding.

Answer (score 1):

**Plan A:**

Continue to export as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, but be sure to set up the import as `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

However, this may tricky if the `CREATE TABLE` statements are buried in the dump.  So...

**Plan B:**

Export and Import as currently being done.  Then, for each table, do

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

If you plan to handle Chinese, `utf8mb4` would be better.
For many uses, the default `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` is fine, but you could consider `utf8_unicode_ci`.